# Counting rows from different tables in same query

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I thought i did something like this before:

```
$reg = mysql_query ("(SELECT count(*) from vouchers) as total_vouchers), 
                     (SELECT count(*) from vouchers WHERE asignado = 1) as vouchers_asignados,
                     (SELECT count(*) from crm) as crm_users,
                     (SELECT count(*) from datos_modificados) as dm_users") or die(mysql_error());
```

But it would return mysql_error near the first `,` :

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as total_vouchers), ((SELECT count(*) from vouchers WHERE asignado = 1) a' at line 1
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add `select` as below

```
$reg = mysql_query ("SELECT
                     (SELECT count(*) from vouchers) as total_vouchers, 
                     (SELECT count(*) from vouchers WHERE asignado = 1) as vouchers_asignados,
                     (SELECT count(*) from crm) as crm_users,
                     (SELECT count(*) from datos_modificados) as dm_users") or die(mysql_error());
```